# grails 2.5, how to delete files in build script with ant

Tags: grails, ant

we need to package up the war, migrations dir, and source.

we first run "grails war"
then we run "grails our-package"

Where our-package is our own packaging script in grails.

Have been trying to add a step which cleans the old build artifacts from the target directory under our grails app, without deleting the war file etc.

```
target ("clean-old" : "cleans artifacts from prev.builds") {
   println "cleaning up zips and tars"
   ant.delete(file: "target/*.zip")
   ant.delete(file: "target/*.gz")
```

}

The above does not work - nothing is deleted.   We assume filesets are the answer, but cant figure out how to use them.

E.g. we have this:

```
ant.fileset(dir: "target") {
    ant.include("*.zip")
    ant.include("*.gz")
}
```

But how to actually delete the files?

We took a blind guess at this:

```
ant.delete() {
    ant.fileset(dir: "target") {
        ant.include("*.zip")
        ant.include("*.gz")
        ant.include("*.tar")
    }
}
```

But it throws an error.

Any ideas?

## Bonus question.

"grails war" does not delete the old war.  I dont want for users to have to enter 3 commands:

```
grails clean-old-war
grails war
grails our-package
```

If we could get a handle on what the current war file will be called, (i.e. the app name and the app version), then there might be a way we can delete all war files except the one we want in "our-package"

1. is there a way to get a handle on app.version from within one of thes ant like build scripts
2. is there a way to delete all wars except one specified?

Answer (score 0):

Trial and error prevailed, the below is not elegant, but works:

```
println "cleaning up zips and tars"
ant.delete(dir:"target", includes: "*.zip")
ant.delete(dir:"target", includes: "*.gz")
```